# Is it possible to put my content menu on top of all?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to  move up my context menu `lol` to the first place above 'Open Link in New Tab'?

[image]

Comment: Well, you can override the entire menu with [contextmenu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contextmenu) (works here on v48) but that would be arrogant I guess :-) Adding a special character like `!` might work but that would definitely look stupid.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible. As by default they set according to this. You can't change them by yourself.